# MS365: Sending encrypted to remote tenants occasionally fails with "user not in tenant"

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365, encryption

We are attempting to replace a secure email gateway solution with MS365's inbuilt email message encryption.

We have a mail flow rule set up to force encryption from a specific sending address to any recipient, as follows:

> **CONDITIONS**:
> Apply rule if:
> Sender is 'alwaysencrypt@example.com'
>
> Do the following:
> Modify message security - Apply Office 365 Message Encryption and rights protection
>
> - Rights protect message with 'Encrypt' (default Encrypt policy)

Now, when we send from `alwaysencrypt` - which is a **Business Basic  licensed account** in this tenant - we have odd results.

1. When sending to a non-MS365 account/tenant/domain, email messages are property delivered and require an OTP code to be sent to validate access.  This works fine.
2. For some MS365 tenant recipients but NOT part of the origin tenant, rights management works properly and properly identifies this external tenant as a recipient and the user is allowed access.
3. For other MS365 tenant recipients who are NOT part of the origin tenant, the system does not allow their user to login and use MS365 tenant auth to access the document and fails with a message akin to `Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Example Tenant' and cannot access the application 'UUID' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.`

It's very *new* that we have this third option happen, and MS365 does NOT offer external tenants the OTP code option.

I don't see a way to address this and permit access to the rights system to external tenants without adding them manually to our origin tenant, and this is a problem because this is an automated system sending encrypted message data as part of alerting systems to external recipients.

Has anyone seen this and does anyone have any idea how we can resolve this to force it to NOT use MS365 tenant authentication for access to encrypted messages and be only OTP-code verification if they are outside the organization?

I should note that MS365 is now forcing the use of Microsoft Purview so the legacy OME solutions will not function, and there's zero documentation on how to alter this or make these revisions as needed.

Note that I have access to a Global Admin on the origin tenant so I SHOULD have access to all the Powershell options if needed.

Comment: This is one of those complex problems that I would open a support case from your tenant for. It's free.

Comment: Actually I think this is self-resolved after spending 12 hours in Microsoft's documentation.  I discovered that Business Basic doesn't have Microsoft Purview for the encryption entitlement.  There's an Azure Information Protection plan that's extra on top of Business Basic to allow encryption.  We're test-running this to see if that fixes this issue.

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that you were using Business Basic. For what it's worth, a Microsoft 365 F1 license will give you AIP and Azure AD P1 (now named Microsoft Entra ID P1), as well as some other things at a cost of $2.25 per user/per month. - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/f1

Comment: @joeqwerty yeah, well for the tenant in question we have (nearly) unlimited Business Basic as a non-profit, and have been using those for service accounts or cases where we need a send/receive mailbox but no actual need for Microsoft apps - this `alwaysencrypt` is an example of such an account.  Under the nonprofit license though it's like $0.50/month/license for AIP P1 so problem solved.  AAD P1 is already included on our tenant with our wide mix of 365 Bus Basic, E1s, E3, and E5 licenses in the tenant, we just didn't want to have to get *another* E3 license at $5/month to get it. :)

Comment: @joeqwerty thank you though for the help, it just took 12 hours for me to dig into the documentation to find it >.>  And then ten seconds to convince the powers that be to spend the fifty cents xD

Comment: Happy to add my two cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in fact, it turns out this isn't a "tenant" issue at all, but a licensing one.  Which is *not* straight-forward to find in the documentation, because the basic Purview pages don't even reference this, it's only in the FAQ which you don't see when you try and debug encryption stuff.

Buried [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/ome-faq) in the Microsoft Purview OME documentation in the FAQ (but NOT anywhere else on the Purview documentation), it indicates what plans Purview is automatically supported in:

> To use Microsoft Purview Message Encryption, you need one of the following plans:
>
> - Microsoft Purview Message Encryption is offered as part of Office 365 Enterprise E3 and E5, Microsoft 365 Enterprise E3 and E5, Microsoft 365 Business Premium, Office 365 A1, A3, and A5, and Office 365 Government G3 and G5. You don't need additional licenses to receive the new protection capabilities powered by Azure Information Protection.
> - You can also add Azure Information Protection Plan 1 to the following plans to receive Microsoft Purview Message Encryption: Exchange Online Plan 1, Exchange Online Plan 2, Office 365 F3, Microsoft 365 Business Basic, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, or Office 365 Enterprise E1.
> - Each user benefiting from Microsoft Purview Message Encryption needs a license to use message encryption.

Unfortunately, this is NOT listed on the MS365 plans pages, and not detailed in any of the other documentation about MS365 plans - at least, not anywhere obvious.

We obtained a license for Azure Information Protection Plan 1 as indicated and attached it to the `alwaysencrypt` user in the origin tenant.  After giving Microsoft time to apply this change and the AIP service to the origin tenant, it works as expected and external tenants can now view the messages, as can non-MS365 recipients as well.

Microsoft has scored a -1 on their documentation today, but at least we resolved this with a simple solution: throwing more money at Microsoft.