# Purview Message Encryption: Require OTP codes for all recipients, and bypass MS365 tenant logins for all outgoing emails

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

> Related: [MS365: Sending encrypted to remote tenants occasionally fails with "user not in tenant"](https://serverfault.com/questions/1143733/ms365-sending-encrypted-to-remote-tenants-occasionally-fails-with-user-not-in)

As in the previous message, we are sending outgoing encrypted messages via MS365 and some remote tenants are unable to view messages.

Before the forced move to Purview in July 2023, when accessing encrypted emails you had the option to request an OTP instead of logging in with your tenant to access things.

We have the option of `OTPEnabled: True` on our OME configuration (according to PowerShell `Get-OMEConfiguration` but since the migration to Purview, we can't *force* everyone to use OTP or even see the "Get OTP code via email" option.

Has anyone figured out a way to force OTP code via email instead of MS365 login in order to get access to a given encrypted message?  If we can force everyone to need OTP codes instead of using MS365-integrated login that'd be great, but I'm not sure where to enforce that, does anyone know how to do that in Purview encryption since legacy OME settings are no longer present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was on a call with Microsoft on the related-linked issue in my question yesterday, and blatantly asked them about whether forcing OTP for everyone was possible.  According to Microsoft support, it turns out that there *is* no way to force OTP for everyone anymore, and that was primarily a legacy Outlook Message Encryption option that is not available in Purview (but available if you use on-prem Exchange still and not MS365 Exchange Online or Hybrid Exchange).

In the Purview world, if someone has an Entra ID (MS365) or a Microsoft account, they *must* use that to authenticate.  For all other receivers, they get OTP prompts in a default Purview setup that Microsoft is now forcing everyone into.

Another -1 to Microsoft for making things that much more complicated and difficult for people.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not an expert is in the subject, but I think the value you want to modify is **SocialIdSignIn** to ***False***.

> -SocialIdSignIn The SocialIdSignIn parameter specifies whether a user is allowed to view an encrypted message in the Microsoft 365 admin
> center using their own social network id (Google, Yahoo, and Microsoft
> account). Valid values are:
>
> $true: Social network ID sign in is allowed. This is the default
> value.
>  $false: Social network ID sign in is not allowed. Whether the
> recipient can use a one-time passcode or their Microsoft 365 work or
> school account is controlled by the OTPEnabled parameter.

Comment: Tried that, didn't do anything almost as if we *can't* shut off SocialIdSignIn.  I'll try this again, but it's almost like Microsoft is telling Entra users to 'screw yourselves' because this is a very broken implementation (see "related" thread for why)

Answer (score 0):

To enforce one-time passcode (OTP) authentication via email instead of MS365 login for accessing encrypted messages, you can utilize the email one-time passcode feature:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/one-time-passcode

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  It explains under *what conditions* it comes into play, but doesn't let us actually *disable* the use of Entra / MS365 logins or social IDs and force OTP, which is the goal here.  And yagmoth555's answer doesn't solve it either, it still forces things to use MS365.  It's like Purview ripped out a feature that was highly desired.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I need starting some more research on this. will give any update late.